# Routing is not working after createing of of react app in MERN app

Tags: reactjs, heroku, react-router, mern

I created a MERN app that has a node.js server.
To host the website on Heroku first I have to create a build folder by it using **npm run build**. After that, I have to add this to my entry point file in my server

```
app.use(express.static("./FRONTEND/build"));
if (process.env.NODE_ENV == "production") {
   app.get("*", (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + './FRONTEND', 'build', 'index.html'));
   })
}
```

I use react-router-dom's **BrowserRouter** to routing through the webpages. But when I uploaded that site on Heroku I found out that the home page is working perfectly but when I route to other pages an error occurred and it says an error occurred in the application.
I tried searching for it and found methods like **adding static.json, using HashRouter, and adding .htaccess**. But nothing works on my site.

Then, theoretically, I re-run the backend with my local computer, so the frontend is also hosted. **The frontend was connected to the backend by this code**.

```
app.use(express.static("./FRONTEND/build"));
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + './FRONTEND', 'build', 'index.html'));
})
```

Hence, I was serving the build for the front-end and also found that routing is not working
in the build also. And the error comes here is

```
ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined
at file:///D:/Yash/React_websites/housedeck-home-services/BACKEND/index.js:26:29
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Yash\React_websites\housedeck-home-services\BACKEND\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (D:\Yash\React_websites\housedeck-home-services\BACKEND\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (D:\Yash\React_websites\housedeck-home-services\BACKEND\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Yash\React_websites\housedeck-home-services\BACKEND\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at D:\Yash\React_websites\housedeck-home-services\BACKEND\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
at param (D:\Yash\React_websites\housedeck-home-services\BACKEND\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:360:14)
at param (D:\Yash\React_websites\housedeck-home-services\BACKEND\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:371:14)
at Function.process_params (D:\Yash\React_websites\housedeck-home-services\BACKEND\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:416:3)
at next (D:\Yash\React_websites\housedeck-home-services\BACK
```

**So, The routing is not working in the build index.html file. I want it to work any suggestions for that.**

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error and I made small change to my code making "/*" instead of "*" and it worked fine for me. And in this case I was using Browser Router and on that it worked fine.

```
app.use(express.static("./FRONTEND/build"));
if (process.env.NODE_ENV == "production") {
app.get("/*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + './FRONTEND', 'build', 'index.html'));
})
}
```